# How do I change the color of an event?

Tags: macos, calendar, ical, color, google-calendar

How do I change the color of an event in Mac High Sierra Calendar?  I am trying to import and synch my Google Calendar events with the Mac High Sierra native calendar (iCal ?).  I can successfully imported and synch the calendar entries, yet they all appear in iCal in the same default calendar color.
Yet, I have not as yet discovered how to synch the individually selected Google Calendar "event" colors (such as, Dk.Blue=Travel, Red=Meeting, Green=Bill pay, Lt.Blue=Work Item, Purple=Anniversary, etc.)

Comment: If it's one Google calendar, it's all one type to 'iCal'.

Comment: What app draws your calendar event? Web app or native app?  I don’t think iCal runs on Sierra so be sure you detail the os and app version strings.

Comment: If you want separate colours for Google calendar events, you need to set up multiple Google calendars. For instance, a work calendar, and a home calendar. (You can have multiple calendars connected to a single Google account.)